# Using the Flickr API

Tags: javascript, jsonp

So I'm using the Flickr API.
I want to show the username of the person who took the picture, looks like this nobody@flickr.com (theNameOfTheUser).

The thing is that I just want to show the actual username and exclude the e-mail.
How can I do that?

[www.johancarleborn.se](http://www.johancarleborn.se) to see what I mean.

```
newPic.innerHTML = "<div class='pic-container'> <p class='title'>" + result.items[i].title + "</p> <a href="+ result.items[i].link +" >  <img src=\'" + result.items[i].media.m + "\'> </a></div><p class='author'>" + result.items[i].author[19] + "</p><p class='published'>" + result.items[i].published + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regexp, something like that:

```
result.items[i].author[19].match(/\(([^)]*)\)/)[1]
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null. What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: That is because non of elements in value of variable result.items[i].author[19]; matches regexp. 
Check value inside result.items[i].author[19]. 
This regexp works perfectly with this string: 
var match = "nobody@flickr.com (CWolves)".match(/\(([^)]*)\)/);
console.dir(match);

Comment: Solved it like this result.items[i].author.match(/\(([^)]*)\)/)[1]
Thank you very much for your help!